# Storing values in JAVA after split

Tags: java

I am working on another assignment and have a question (first of many I'm sure). I am working on a program that validates and sets IP addresses, subnet masks, default gateway and DNS. In my validIP method which checks to see if the IP is valid, I have the following code:

```
try {
    if (ip == null || ip.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    String[] parts = ip.split( "\\." );
    if ( parts.length != 4 ) {
        return false;
    }

    for ( String s : parts ) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt( s );
        if ( (i < 0) || (i > 255) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(ip.endsWith(".")) {
            return false;
    }

    return true;
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    return false;
}
```

This efficiently checks and makes sure its a valid format. Now, I want to create another method that will make sure the address is assignable. IE if its a class address that the 2,3,4 octets are in valid range. How would I store the information from the split so I can compare? Like if its class a (first octet is between 1-127), I need to compare the other octets to be sure they are not all 0s or 255s.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: First be sure you know all the values that constitute valid normal IP addresses (not broadcast addresses). Then experiment with your code and print statements. This is a good problem for you to think through. If you've gotten this far you should be able to use some similar constructs to test for other cases.  Solving that problem may seem hard but it's exactly what you need to do to become a good programmer. Don't give up too easily and take the easy way out.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right, you want to store the parsed int values in an array:

```
int[] parsed = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    parsed[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
}
```

Then you can test them:

```
if (parsed[0] >= 1 && parsed[0] <= 127) {
    if ((parsed[1] != 0 && parsed[1] != 255)
            || (parsed[2] != 0 && parsed[2] != 255)
            || (parsed[3] != 0 && parsed[3] != 255)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. My only question is how is the new parsed array getting the values that have already been stored in the parts array? What I really want to do is create another boolean method called assignableIP and send the verified IP address to it to check the class and be sure that the address is actually assignable.

Comment: We set the values there. `parsed[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);` This means that e.g. the value of index 0 is as `String` in `parts[0]` and as `int` in `parsed[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply a logic like this. Keep a Boolean value and update if you got a `0 or 255.` for classes either use if-conditions or switch-cases.

```
String[] parts = {"192","255","255","255"};
            boolean valid = true;
            for(int i = 0;i<parts.length;i++){
                for(int j = i+1 ; j< parts.length;j++){
                    if(parts[j].equalsIgnoreCase("255") || parts[j].equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
                        valid = false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Java assignment, use what Java has to offer: object-orientation. Create a class representing IP address. Dedicated objects will be easier to pass around and interact with.
Simple example based on your code:

```
public class IpAddress {
    public final int partOne;
    public final int partTwo;
    public final int partThree;
    public final int partFour;

    public IpAddress(int partOne, int partTwo, int partThree, int partFour) {
        this.partOne = partOne;
        this.partTwo = partTwo;
        this.partThree = partThree;
        this.partFour = partFour;
    }

    public static IpAddress valueOf(String ip) {
        if (ip == null || ip.isEmpty())
            return null;

        String[] parts = ip.split("\\.");
        if (parts.length != 4)
            return null;

        if (ip.endsWith("."))
            return null;

        int[] intParts = new int[4];

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int intPart = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
                if (intPart < 0 || intPart > 255)
                    return null;

                intParts[i] = intPart;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return null;
        }

        return new IpAddress(intParts[0], intParts[1], intParts[2], intParts[3]);
    }
}
```